# RPM or YUM equivalent of apt-get install libgraphicsmagick1-dev

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, apt, rpm

I was using Ubuntu for development and one of the dependencies needs

```
apt-get libgraphicsmagick1-dev
```

now I need to deploy to a AWS EC2 which runs AMI and only support YUM or RPM, what the the equivalent command for the above? Please note that I cannot change the server OS choice. Thanks.

Comment: What do the yum and rpm manuals say?

Comment: sorry, I am new and I didn't know where to look. I only used Linux for a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
yum search graphics magick dev
[ ... ]
===================================== N/S Matched: graphics, magick, dev ======================================
GraphicsMagick-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and header files for GraphicsMagick app development
```

Thus, the equivalent is `yum install GraphicsMagick-devel` ...